# Linking to Other Excel Sheets Greyed Out (Excel 2011 Mac)

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2011

I just got a file from my colleague which has some broken links. They were broken because the path to the cells pointed directly to a file on her computer. She sent over those files, and now I have to repair the links. However, Excel won't let me choose to change source to those new files. It will let me choose to replace the source with some other Excel files, but the ones I want are greyed out. How do I make it so Excel will let me use those files as source?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem with files that were being shared via Google Drive.  The solution that worked for me was:

1. Open the destination file - i.e. the one that is being linked to.
2. If that in turn links anywhere choose `Ignore Links`
3. Save the destination file
4. Close the destination file
5. Re-open the master file - i.e. the one you are linking out from.
6. Choose `Edit Links`
7. The previously greyed out files should now be no longer greyed out.

Have tried this with Excel 2008 and Excel 2011.  2011 was on Yosemite.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that the files don't have a proper extension? Besides, you can manually edit the formula, and type in the full path to the desired files. Ideally, you should use a relative-path form: see, for instance the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10734082/relative-paths-links-in-excel).

Comment: I would manually edit, but there are literally thousands of cells that are showing up as #N/A. Yeah, the files all have proper extensions.

Comment: So it looks like Excel doesn't like linking to workbooks with multiple worksheets. This is not going to be fun.